# Command Prompt won't change directory to any folder on desktop

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line

I have been trying to get command prompt to change directory to any of the folders on my desktop, but it keeps on saying, "The system can not find the path specified." It changes to desktop via:

```
cd desktop
```

but it doesn't work for any other folders.

[[image: image of desktop and command prompt]Click to enlarge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eFhM.jpg)

Comment: what do you see if you type `dir`? it will show you what folders and files are present. Also you can use the tab key to autocomplete names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple locations that feed icons into your "Desktop."  For example C:\Users\Public\Public Desktop is one.

[image]

To figure out where that Program folder really is, right click the folder on your desktop, then click Properties, then click the Security tab.  At the top you will see the actual path of the folder.

If you go back to your cmd prompt, you can change directories to that folder instead.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @ShahmirS You're welcome!  Glad I could help.  :)